# Why does the second condition fail to execute correctly?

Tags: ssis

I have the following expression in a Derived Column transformation.

```
((DT_STR,1,1252)outGender == "M" || (DT_I1)outGender == 1) ? 1 : (((DT_STR,1,1252)outGender == "F" || (DT_I1)outGender == 2) ? 2 : 3
```

When I run the package, if the "outGender" column contains a "1" or "M", the GenderId column becomes 1. If "outGender" is "2", the GenderId column is "2". So far, this is correct. If, however, "outGender" contains "F" then GenderId will be NULL. This is wrong.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it? If I switch the condition strings, placing the "F" conditions in the first part of the expression and "M" conditions in the second part, then NULL appears in the GenderId column for rows when the "outGender" column contains "M" values.

Comment: What type of column is outGender coming into the Derived Column transformation? I can't even build a package that doesn't throw a cast error when I'm running your transform.

Comment: Also, based purely on what you posed it's invalid because your parentheses aren't closed. This may be your root issue.

Comment: @Kyle - The parenthesis do close. It was a bad copy / paste...

Answer (score 0):

So this transform works fine without casting your values as integers:

```
((DT_STR,1,1252)outgender == "M" || (DT_STR,1,1252)outgender == "1") ? 1 : (((DT_STR,1,1252)outgender == "F" || (DT_STR,1,1252)outgender == "2") ? 2 : 3)
```

And if outGender is already a DT_STR type you can simplify it and just use

```
(outgender == "M" || outgender == "1") ? 1 : ((outgender == "F" || outgender == "2") ? 2 : 3)
```